# Differentiate human generated event from browser generated in old IEs

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a `input[type=checkbox]` and when I change its `checked` property this will not generate a `change` event in modern browsers.

IE9- though fires a `propertychange` event when I do `element.checked = true;`.

How can I differentiate a `propertychange` event that is generated by the browser but consequence of a code changing the `checkbox` from a real human checking the `checkbox`?

My only idea after some thinking is to do this check:

```
if (
    document.activeElement != event.target 
    && event.type == 'propertychange' 
    && event.propertyName == 'checked'
) // its syntetic
```

but this will fail in cases that the checkbox has `focus` and is changed by code, and also fail if the checkbox is changed via `<label>`.

Is there any property in the IE9- `event` I can check this, or a way to detect this?

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uuwe7ojc/

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve?  Are you trying to get notified when the property is changed programmatically, but not when it's changed by the user?  Or vice versa?  So, rather than asking for help with a specific solution path, please describe the overall problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @jfriend00 I want to add a event handler to a input that runs code only when a user change is made.

Answer (score 1):

You can just listen for the `click` event and you will get notified whenever the user changes the property, but not when it changes programmatically.  I've tested this in Chrome and IE 9, 10, 11 and it works for a click on the checkbox, a click on the containing label and even a space bar to change the checkbox when it's focused.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/tdhpaqs8/

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // checkbox was changed by the user
});
```

Comment: what if the user has focus on the checkbox and uses space bar to check/uncheck it

Comment: @chiliNUT - that works too - it generates the click event.  Try the demo I linked.

Comment: weird that that triggers the click event instead of keydown or something. good to know!

Comment: @chiliNUT - there is a keydown event before the click event.  But, what matters here is that the spacebar triggers a click event.  I think all this click event stuff on the checkbox was designed before they had the change event or before they decided to use it for checkboxes so thus it is the more common denominator for older browsers.